# How did Alluka Zoldyck obtain her powers?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Due to some recent news about the *Hunter x Hunter* manga being continued, I decided to re-watch the anime and some question popped into my head. I haven't finished it yet, but I don't remember any explanation of the origin of Alluka's power the first time I watched it.

I've watched some videos but they don't really explain my question. I also couldn't find an answer here.

Was the origin of Alluka's power ever explained in the anime or perhaps in the manga?

Comment: Would it satify you to claim that she is a "genius" nen user as described in the yorknew city arc?  The main example is the future telling girl in that arc whose powerful ability appeared with no real training and she doesn't have that much control over it.  I don't know if this has been directly stated in canon so I'm not comfortable putting this as an answer.  (She could have some weird backstory we don't know yet.)

Comment: wouldn't this be a future question ? i think the powers will get resolved only after we get to explore the dark continent and its creatures more

Answer (score 3):

It has been confirmed that Nanika came from the Dark Continent and evidence suggests that Nanika is Ai, the desire of co-dependence.

As to how Nanika started possessing Alluka, we don't know for sure but seeing how Zigg Zoldyck went to the Dark Continent, it is possible he brought it back to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Alluka isn't a human. She's a different being which there are six of them in the world that are known of. Not sure, but I think they came from the Dark Continent.

Comment: While this fact might be correct, could you clarify on how she obtained her power? Did you mean because she is from the Dark Continent (why)? Consider [edit] and expand the answer.